# Assuming a ray defined by a starting point and a direction. How can I tell if a plane is behind it or in front of it?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, 3d, collision-detection

If I have a ray defined by a starting point and a direction, and a plane defined by its normal and its distance from the origin, how can I tell if the plane is in front versus behind the ray?

By behind, I mean that if there had a second ray starting at the same point than the first but heading in the opposite direction, the plane would be behind the first ray if the second ray would hit the plane.

Comment: I think the first "plane" you wrote was intended to be "ray." Is my hunch right?

Comment: Would a better way to phrase your question be: "how can I tell if the plane intersects the ray or not?"

Comment: Substitute the front point of your ray in the plane equation and if it comes out to be less than zero than it is behind it or if it is zero than it is intersecting the plane and if greater than zero than it is in front of it

Comment: I saw the answer to someone asking this, but the solution proposed would detect collisions both when the plane was in front or behind the ray.

Comment: @user291957 I don't undertand?

Comment: @MickaelBergeronNéron Can you *please* clarify what "in front of a ray" and "in back of" a ray or plane means? Right now it's hard to understand what you mean, unless it's something like in my comment about the ray intersecting the plane.

Comment: @MickaelBergeronNéron OK: Thanks for the edits. I think my hunch that you are asking "does the ray hit the plane or not?" is correct. That seems to be a much simpler way to express it, but let me know if there's some difference I am overlooking.

Comment: @rschwieb Exactly. The reason why I am specifying behind versus in front is that the solutions I have found so far don't make this distinction. These solutions will detect a collision even when the plane is behind the ray.

Comment: sorry my thought went some where else and that's not the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the base of the ray is not on the plane.

Translate everything so that you have a vector $n$ normal to the plane whose arrow tip lies on the base of the ray $r$. If $r\cdot n < 0$, then the ray is tipped "toward" the plane and will eventually intersect it. If $r\cdot n=0$, the ray is parallel to the plane. If $r\cdot n>0$ the ray is directed so that it will never hit the plane.